# React Social using Firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I followed a tutorial for setting up React Social using Firebase as a backend. After configuring Firebase (through 'firebase init'), I now get this error in the web browser when I enter 'npm start' at the command line. I'm not sure how to interpret this or how to fix it. Any help would be appreciated!

Html Webpack Plugin:
  ReferenceError: features is not defined

- index.html:701 
  C:/RS_tut/react-social-network/public/index.html:701:10
- index.html:704 ./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./public/index.html.module.exports
  C:/RS_tut/react-social-network/public/index.html:704:3
- index.js:264 
  [react-social-network]/[html-webpack-plugin]/index.js:264:16
- From previous event:
- index.js:252 HtmlWebpackPlugin.executeTemplate
  [react-social-network]/[html-webpack-plugin]/index.js:252:6
- index.js:137 
  [react-social-network]/[html-webpack-plugin]/index.js:137:18
- From previous event:
- index.js:132 Compiler.
  [react-social-network]/[html-webpack-plugin]/index.js:132:8
- Tapable.js:206 Compiler.applyPluginsAsyncSeries
  [react-social-network]/[tapable]/lib/Tapable.js:206:13
- Compiler.js:358 Compiler.emitAssets
  [react-social-network]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:358:8
- Compiler.js:57 onCompiled
  [react-social-network]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:57:19
- Compiler.js:514 applyPluginsAsync.err
  [react-social-network]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:514:14
- Tapable.js:202 next
  [react-social-network]/[tapable]/lib/Tapable.js:202:11
- CachePlugin.js:78 Compiler.
  [react-social-network]/[webpack]/lib/CachePlugin.js:78:5
- Tapable.js:206 Compiler.applyPluginsAsyncSeries
  [react-social-network]/[tapable]/lib/Tapable.js:206:13
- Compiler.js:511 compilation.seal.err
  [react-social-network]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:511:11
- Tapable.js:195 Compilation.applyPluginsAsyncSeries
  [react-social-network]/[tapable]/lib/Tapable.js:195:46
- Compilation.js:680 self.applyPluginsAsync.err
  [react-social-network]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:680:19
- Tapable.js:195 Compilation.applyPluginsAsyncSeries
  [react-social-network]/[tapable]/lib/Tapable.js:195:46
- Compilation.js:671 self.applyPluginsAsync.err
  [react-social-network]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:671:11
- Tapable.js:195 Compilation.applyPluginsAsyncSeries
  [react-social-network]/[tapable]/lib/Tapable.js:195:46
- Compilation.js:666 self.applyPluginsAsync.err
  [react-social-network]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:666:10
- Tapable.js:195 Compilation.applyPluginsAsyncSeries
  [react-social-network]/[tapable]/lib/Tapable.js:195:46
- Compilation.js:662 sealPart2
  [react-social-network]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:662:9
- Tapable.js:195 Compilation.applyPluginsAsyncSeries
  [react-social-network]/[tapable]/lib/Tapable.js:195:46
- Compilation.js:605 Compilation.seal
  [react-social-network]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:605:8

---

this is my index.html

---

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Welcome to Firebase Hosting</title>

    <!-- update the version number as needed -->
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/5.0.4/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <!-- include only the Firebase features as you need -->
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/5.0.4/firebase-auth.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/5.0.4/firebase-database.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/5.0.4/firebase-messaging.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/5.0.4/firebase-storage.js"></script>
    <!-- initialize the SDK after all desired features are loaded -->
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/init.js"></script>

    <style media="screen">
      body { background: #ECEFF1; color: rgba(0,0,0,0.87); font-family: Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
      #message { background: white; max-width: 360px; margin: 100px auto 16px; padding: 32px 24px; border-radius: 3px; }
      #message h2 { color: #ffa100; font-weight: bold; font-size: 16px; margin: 0 0 8px; }
      #message h1 { font-size: 22px; font-weight: 300; color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6); margin: 0 0 16px;}
      #message p { line-height: 140%; margin: 16px 0 24px; font-size: 14px; }
      #message a { display: block; text-align: center; background: #039be5; text-transform: uppercase; text-decoration: none; color: white; padding: 16px; border-radius: 4px; }
      #message, #message a { box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24); }
      #load { color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); text-align: center; font-size: 13px; }
      @media (max-width: 600px) {
        body, #message { margin-top: 0; background: white; box-shadow: none; }
        body { border-top: 16px solid #ffa100; }
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="message">
      <h2>Welcome</h2>
      <h1>Firebase Hosting Setup Complete</h1>
      <p>You're seeing this because you've successfully setup Firebase Hosting. Now it's time to go build something extraordinary!</p>
      <a target="_blank" href="https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/">Open Hosting Documentation</a>
    </div>
    <p id="load">Firebase SDK Loading&hellip;</p>

    <script>
      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        // // ðŸ”¥ðŸ”¥ðŸ”¥ðŸ”¥ðŸ”¥ðŸ”¥ðŸ”¥ðŸ”¥ðŸ”¥ðŸ”¥ðŸ”¥ðŸ”¥ðŸ”¥ðŸ”¥ðŸ”¥ðŸ”¥ðŸ”¥ðŸ”¥ðŸ”¥ðŸ”¥ðŸ”¥ðŸ”¥ðŸ”¥ðŸ”¥ðŸ”¥ðŸ”¥ðŸ”¥ðŸ”¥ðŸ”¥ðŸ”¥ðŸ”¥
        // // The Firebase SDK is initialized and available here!
        //
        // firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => { });
        // firebase.database().ref('/path/to/ref').on('value', snapshot => { });
        // firebase.messaging().requestPermission().then(() => { });
        // firebase.storage().ref('/path/to/ref').getDownloadURL().then(() => { });
        //
        // // ðŸ”¥ðŸ”¥ðŸ”¥ðŸ”¥ðŸ”¥ðŸ”¥ðŸ”¥ðŸ”¥ðŸ”¥ðŸ”¥ðŸ”¥ðŸ”¥ðŸ”¥ðŸ”¥ðŸ”¥ðŸ”¥ðŸ”¥ðŸ”¥ðŸ”¥ðŸ”¥ðŸ”¥ðŸ”¥ðŸ”¥ðŸ”¥ðŸ”¥ðŸ”¥ðŸ”¥ðŸ”¥ðŸ”¥ðŸ”¥ðŸ”¥

        try {
          let app = firebase.app();
          let features = ['auth', 'database', 'messaging', 'storage'].filter(feature => typeof app[feature] === 'function');
          document.getElementById('load').innerHTML = `Firebase SDK loaded with ${features.join(', ')}`;
        } catch (e) {
          console.error(e);
          document.getElementById('load').innerHTML = 'Error loading the Firebase SDK, check the console.';
        }
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you initialized Firebase Hosting you overwrited your index.html with the Firebase boilerplate that erased your react initialization. You can fix it reverting to a previous version or adding your react root element.